# How can I get a list of all windows, currently on the screen, in swift?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics, swift

How can I get a list of all windows, currently on the screen, in **[swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/)**? (all examples are preceded by `import Cocoa`)

In **objective-c** I can run the following code successfully:

```
CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
```

But when I run the equivalent in **swift**(using the playground to test):

```
let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kcGNullWindowID)
```

I get an error telling me that I have an `Use of unresolved identifier 'kcGNullWindowID'`.

After playing around with the help of the [quartz documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference/Constants/Constants.html) for a while I have gotten to:

```
let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly), CGWindowListOption(0))
```

But it still does not work as I am receiving a `{__NSArrayM}` object, which I do not know how to access.

Am I on the right track or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: That's an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Is the objc version, `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` thread safe? Or does it have to run from main thread?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's an example in Swift 2.0, which also demonstrates multiple options.

```
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.ExcludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.OptionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `takeUnretainedValue()` or `takeRetainedValue()` on `windowList`.

Check out Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) and read the section called *Working with Cocoa Data Types* and look for *Unmanaged Objects*.

Here is a concrete example:

```
import Cocoa

let windowInfosRef = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly), CGWindowID(0))
let windowInfos = windowInfosRef.takeRetainedValue().__conversion() // cast to swift dictionary
println(windowInfos) // print the swift dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version for Swift 1.2. It's more explicit about types, since we know the function returns an array of dictionaries with string keys.

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly)
let cfInfoList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0)).takeRetainedValue()
let infoList = cfInfoList as NSArray as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```