# How to get window list from core-grapics API with swift

Tags: macos, swift, core-graphics

I´m trying to get a list of windows on OSX from the core-graphics API with Swift (to capture an image of them later on). After some research I found the CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo Objective-C API call with the following signature:

```
CFArrayRef CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
   CGWindowListOption option,
   CGWindowID relativeToWindow
);
```

> Parameters
>
> option: The options describing which window dictionaries to
>   return. Typical options let you return dictionaries for all windows or
>   for windows above or below the window specified in the
>   relativeToWindow parameter. For more information, see Window List
>   Option Constants.
>
> relativeToWindow: The ID of the window to use as a
>   reference point when determining which other window dictionaries to
>   return. For options that do not require a reference window, this
>   parameter can be kCGNullWindowID.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html

In my swift application I tried to use it like this:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreFoundation

let option: CGWindowListOption = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly
let relativeToWindow: CGWindowID = kCGNullWindowID

let info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(option, relativeToWindow)
```

But XCode (playground) tells me

- it can´t use an int as CGWindowListOption (kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly == 0)
- kCGNullWindowID is an unresolved identifier

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that this is not an Objective-C API. This is a C API. (That doesn't change a lot; but it changes where you look for information.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` is an `Int`, you have to *convert*
  that to `CGWindowListOption` aka `UInt32`.
- The C definition

  ```
  #define kCGNullWindowID ((CGWindowID)0)
  ```

  is not imported into Swift, therefore you have to use the constant
  `0`.
- In addition, `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` returns an `Unmanaged<CFArray>!`, therefore you have to call `takeRetainedValue()`
  on the returned value (as documented in ["Working with Cocoa Data Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)).

Together:

```
let option = CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly)
let relativeToWindow = CGWindowID(0)
let info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(option, relativeToWindow).takeRetainedValue()
```

Then you can enumerate this array of dictionaries with

```
for dict in info as! [ [ String : AnyObject] ] {
    // ...
}
```

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
if let info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(.optionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID) as? [[ String : Any]] {
    for dict in info {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: See answer regarding Swift 2.0 for updated example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31367468/1184231

Comment: Excuse me, then how to get those windows reference?