# How to get window id from the title by swift3

Tags: swift3, macos-sierra

How can I get a `CGWindowID` from the title of it?

I thought I can get list of titles by this code

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31367468/1536527

But it seems there is no info for title of the windows.

How can I get `CGWindowID` or any info to specify a window by title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code snippet you posted seems to work for me. All I did was to iterate over the dictionary and find the window info for a given window title.

Here is the code:

```
func getWindowInfo(pname: String) -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var answer = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]


    infoList?.forEach{eachDict in
        eachDict.keys.forEach{ eachKey in
            if (eachKey == "kCGWindowName" && eachDict[eachKey] != nil ){
                let name = eachDict[eachKey] as? String ?? ""
                print (name)
                if ( name == pname){
                    print("******** Found **********")
                    answer = eachDict as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                }
            }
            print(eachKey , "-->" , eachDict[eachKey])
        }
    }
    return answer
}
```

With the above function, I am able to get a window's details, including name for example.

I hope it works for you too.