# NSAccessibilityNotificationName.mainWindowChanged observer to be notified when main window changes

Tags: swift, macos, nsnotificationcenter, accessibility-api

I would like to be notified when the main window of the frontmost app changes i.e changing a tab in a browser, changing a document in SublimeText etc. and get the title of that current main window. I'm quite new to Swift so I'd appreciate any kind of info/help.

I've written a piece of code to observe the frontmostapp by using addobserver on the didActivateAppNotification object. It successfully prints out the frontmost app everytime it changes to a new one.

So I also wanna do the same with main window of the frontmost app. However, all I can do is to get the window lists of the frontmost app via CGWindowListOption as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094375/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-windows-currently-on-the-screen-in-swift#24094636), then scroll through it to get a list of the windows of frontmost app and filter it to get the mainwindow. But I don't want a polling solution, which is to get this list every second. Instead I'd like to get use of a notification observer so that I can actually ask when the mainwindow changes. -I've also tried some Applescript solutions, they all need to be polling solutions.

I couldn't find any tutorials, examples of NSAccessibilityNotificationName classes as it says they require special handling in [Apple Dev Forums](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1529733-nsaccessibilitypostnotification). How could I observe those notifications for external applications? (specifically mainWindowChanged in my example)

Cheers, happy coding!

```
class activeApp: NSObject {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(printMe(notification:)),
            name: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification,
            object:nil)

    }
    @objc func printMe(notification: NSNotification) {
        let app = notification.userInfo!["NSWorkspaceApplicationKey"] as! NSRunningApplication
        print(app.localizedName!)
    }
}
let runme = activeApp()
RunLoop.main.run()
```